# Magento 2.3.2 sort the product collection by attributes

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-collection, sorting

I want to sort the product collection by attributes. I want to apply multiple sorting to the product collection need to sort by NEW, ONSALE, and POSITION

For example when going to any listing page then first it will be showing by position then NEW product than on Sale product.

Is it possible to apply multiple sorting to the product collection?

Below is my code logic

```
$subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('on_sale', 'ASC');
$subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'DESC');
$subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position','DESC');
```

Comment: You should be able to apply as many `->setOrder` method as you want on a collection.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have updated my question. I had tried with the given code but it is not showing the accurate result.

Comment: I think this is because you return a new collection each time you might be able to "chain" these methods

`$subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('on_sale', 'ASC')->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'DESC')->addAttributeToSort('position','DESC')` or keeping your way you need to apply the new filter on the collection result `$c1 = $subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('on_sale', 'ASC'); $c2 = $c1->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'DESC');`

Comment: Thanks let me try with this.